# Dates switching from string to dd-mm-yyyy in VBA filter

Tags: excel, vba

```
inout.Activate

inout.Range("$A$1", Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 10)).AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & Format(beginweek, "yyyy-mm-dd"), Operator:=xlAnd, _
Criteria2:="<=" & Format(eindeweek, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

"In this last sentence the macro gives me an error".

Comment: What's the error you're getting?  Make sure to qualify ALL of your ranges... you may want a `With` statement to make life easier... and make sure you're selecting a complete range, e.g., `Range("A$1:A$" & lastRow)`

Comment: Break out your inputs in to discreet variables that you can examine at runtime. This will help you learn about debugging a problem solving. Then give us more information about the error and at which line. If you put everything on one line then it's harder to see what caused the error. So break that down in to it's parts!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry is my first time that i make a question.  My error is FOUT 1004 TIJDENS UITVOERING. METHODE AUTOFILTER VAN KLASSE RANGE IS MISLUKT.  How i can send my query that you can see it.

Comment: I am trying to filter a data with start and end date range. and then pass the data to another sheet. At the moment of carrying out this sentence, it gives an error.

Comment: beginweek = InputBox("Gelieve begindatum in te voegen DD/MM/YYYY")
eindeweek = InputBox("gelieve einddatum in te voegen DD/MM/YYYY")

beginweekform = Format(beginweek, "short date")
eindeweekform = Format(eindeweek, "short date")

inout.Activate

inout.Range("$A$1", Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(0,10)). AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & Format(beginweek, "yyyy-mm-dd"), Operator:=xlAnd, _
Criteria2:="<=" & Format(eindeweek, "yyyy-mm-dd")